# React - Set loading state only on specific clicked button

Tags: reactjs

Here is my current code

```
class cart extends Component {
    state = { loading: [] };

    addToCart = (e, id) => {
        let loading = this.state.loading.slice();
        loading[e] = true;
        this.setState({
            loading,
        })
    };
    render() {
        const { data } = this.props;

        return (
            <div>
            {data.map(catering => {
                const { menus } = catering;

                return (
                    <Row>
                    {menus.map(menu => (
                        <Col xs={12} md={12} lg={6} key={menu.id} className="m-bottom-15">
                        <Card style={{ height: '165px', border: 0, overflow: 'hidden' }}>


                        <CardActions>
                        <LoadingButton
                        className="button small primary pull-right"
                        loading={thi.state.loading || false}
                        onClick={e => this.addToCart(e, menu.id)}
                        >
                        <MdAdd size={18} color={white} />
                        <span className="font-14 font-400">Add to cart</span>
                        </LoadingButton>

                        </CardActions>
                        </Card>
                        </Col>
                        ))}
                    </Row>

                    );
            }
        }
```

There will be around 20 button when the `map` function is done.

What I want to achieve is: every time users click `add to cart` button, I will call the ajax to save the cart and show loading for the specific clicked button.
After ajax is done, return the state back to normal.

On my current code I haven't put my ajax call yet, I still want to make sure the loading button work on press. Right now its not working.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is some error in your addToCart method. You should use id as index of loading and set loading array to state as this:

```
addToCart = (e, id) => {
    let loading = this.state.loading.slice();
    loading[id] = true;
    this.setState({
        loading: loading
    });
};
```

Also, in your render method, change this.state.loading to this.state.loading[menu.id]:

```
<LoadingButton
    className="button small primary pull-right"
    loading={this.state.loading[menu.id] || false}
    onClick={e => this.addToCart(e, menu.id)}
>
```

When ajax call is done, you just call setState function which sets loading array values to false in callback method.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of maintaining `bool` in loading `array`, maintain the **menu ids**, whenever Add button is clicked, push the id of that item into loading `array`. When generating the card check whether loading `array` have that `id` or not, if yes then show loading otherwise show the card.

Write it like this:

```
class cart extends Component {

    state = { loading:  []};

    addToCart = (e, id) => {
        let loading = this.state.loading.slice();
        loading.push(id);
        this.setState({
            loading
        })
    };

    render() {
        const { data } = this.props;

        return (
            <div>
            {data.map((catering,i) => {
                const { menus } = catering;
                return (
                    <Row>
                        {menus.map(menu => {
                            return this.state.loading.indexOf(menu.id) >= 0 ?
                                <Col xs={12} md={12} lg={6} key={menu.id} className="m-bottom-15">
                                    <Card style={{ height: '165px', border: 0, overflow: 'hidden' }}>
                                        <CardActions>
                                            <LoadingButton
                                                className="button small primary pull-right"
                                                loading={thi.state.loading || false}
                                                onClick={e => this.addToCart(e, menu.id)}
                                            >
                                                <MdAdd size={18} color={white} />
                                                <span className="font-14 font-400">Add to cart</span>
                                            </LoadingButton>
                                        </CardActions>
                                    </Card>
                                </Col>
                            :
                            /*Loading icon*/
                        })}
                    </Row>
                )
            })}
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. this code is almost correct. I need to fix the <LoadingButton> section to compatible with your current code. because on render it will make the button become loading.

Answer (score 0):

for the hooks guys this is what I did

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState([]);
<button
        type="button"
        disabled={isLoading[item.username]}
        className="btn btn-success btn-rounded btn-sm my-0"
        onClick={()=>activateOrDeactivate( item.activated,item.username)}
      >      {isLoading[item.username] && <i className="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin"></i>}
      {isLoading[item.username]&& <span> Activating...</span>}
      {!isLoading[item.username]&& <span>Activate</span>}</button>


 const activateOrDeactivate = (valTrueOrFalse,newusername) => {
    let loading = isLoading.slice();
    loading[newusername] = true;
    setIsLoading(loading)
    let config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + state.token
      },
    };

    api.post(
      "process-activation",
      {
        activated: !valTrueOrFalse,
        username:newusername
      },
      config
    ).then(
      response => {
        getAllUsers()
        let loading = isLoading.slice();
        loading[newusername] = false;
        setIsLoading(loading)
```